# Yocto and TPM: /dev/tpm is missing on the final image

Tags: yocto, tpm

I'm using Yocto Warrior and SPI TPM ST33HTPH2X32AHD4.

I added these recipes: tpm2-abrmd, tpm2-tools, rng-tools, tpm2-tss.
Also I set the following switch on the Kernel:

```
CONFIG_TCG_TPM=m
CONFIG_TCG_CRB=y
CONFIG_TCG_TIS=m
CONFIG_TCG_TIS_CORE=m
CONFIG_TCG_TIS_SPI=m
CONFIG_TCG_TIS_ST33ZP24=m
CONFIG_TCG_TIS_ST33ZP24_SPI=m
CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_TPM=m
```

finally, I inserted on dts:

```
&spi0 {
         status = "okay";
         clock-frequency = <20000000>;
         // st tpm
         st,st33htpm-spi@0 {
            compatible = "st,st33htpm-spi";
            spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
            reg = <0>;
      };
};
```

I built the image but I can't able to use the TPM... each tpm utility doesn't find /dev/tpm. How can I do this ? Should I updated also the u-boot ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the modules are installed into the rootfs? If you do not have the kernel-modules package in IMAGE_INSTALL, modules can be compiled but not installed to the rootfs.

Please verify whether:

- the TPM modules are there (in the /lib/modules/)
- verify whether you could load the module manually

No need to change U-Boot to have the TPM available in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved. This is my fault because I used a patch with *git diff* for both Kernel-Switches and DTB.
Kernel-Switches have to modify by adding a simple enable.cfg file